# The best way to snatch an expiring domain?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

There's a domain that I've been looking to acquire that is expiring on the 30th of this month.  I don't think it is very popular, and the guy hasn't seemed to update the website in two years now.

So, I was doing some research and came across [this site](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/archive/2005/03/how-to-snatch-an-expiring-domain) that seems to review some "snatching" services, but the article is quite outdated.  So, I'm wondering if anyone can offer any newer information on the topic, or whether the recommend any services for helping me acquire the site in question?

Comment: If the owner cares about the domain, you will have no chance of snatching it. If it is abandoned, why not talk to the owner instead?

Comment: [Drop Catching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_drop_catching) seems to be a new term for this.

Answer (score 3):

This website is from 2005-03 ... things have changed  ..

Domains are not easy to snatch, read about the grace and redemption period.
This biggest problem  now is mostly Domain Tasting .. ...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_tasting

Comment: Good info on Domain Tasting. Sounds like it decreased quite in the last few years b/c (at least for TLDs) bulk tasting gets penalized (same wiki article)

Answer (score 1):

You must be aware of the redemption period. Depending on the TLD, there's a specific period after the domain expiration where the domain can be renewed only from the original registrant.

You said the domain is expiring the 30th of this month. I suggest you to wait at least the 1st of the next month to check whether the domain was renewed or not. Chances are the domain will be renewed and you paid a backorder service for nothing.

If, and only if, the domain was not renewed during the redemption period, you can start thinking about a backorder service to register the domain when it becomes available.